# Como levantar el dialogo de activación de GPS en Java

Tags: java, android, gps

Hola estoy tratando de que al intentar enviar mi posición GPS si el GPS esta apagado levante esta ventana solicitando que active el GPS. Estoy haciendolo para Android con Java. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda agregar el código que estés actualmente tratando, de ahí te podríamos brindar ideas, ¿Cual es la condición que determina abrir el diálogo? saludos.

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que no se, cual es el código que ejecuta ese dialogo, porque eso se ejecuta cuando tengo el GPS apagado y quiero intentar obtener la posición GPS. Ya con mi APP instalada y con los permisos de GPS aceptados.

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar una solicitud a los servicios de ubicación [SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) debes establecer lo siguiente:

En tu archivo `build.gradle` debes de agregar la dependencia:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Y establecer el permiso necesario:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Implementación del código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

...

private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
private static final int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT = 3;
private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    initGoogleAPIClient();
        checkPermissions();

    ....
}

private void initGoogleAPIClient() {
        // Sin el diálogo de ubicación automática del cliente API de Google no funcionará
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestLocationPermission();
            } else {
                openDialog();
            }
        } else {
            openDialog();
        }
    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT);
        }
    }

    // Broadcast  para verificar el estado del GPS
    private BroadcastReceiver gpsLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction()).matches(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                // Compruebe si el GPS está activado o desactivado
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "GPS está habilitado en su dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Si el GPS está apagado, muestre el diálogo de ubicación
                        new Handler().postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            openDialog();
        }
    };

    private void openDialog() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); //5 sec Time interval for location update
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); //Setting priority of Location request to high

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                } catch (ApiException exception) {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // Todos los cambios requeridos se realizaron con éxito.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS habilitado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // Se le pidió al usuario que cambiara la configuración, pero decidió no hacerlo.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS no esta habilitado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //openDialog();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Mostrar el cuadro de diálogo de ubicación
                    if (googleApiClient == null) {
                        initGoogleAPIClient();
                        openDialog();
                    } else {
                        openDialog();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permiso de ubicación denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Registra el BroadcastReceiver para verificar el estado del GPS
        registerReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Anular el BroadcastReceiver al destruir
        if (gpsLocationReceiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver);
    }

}
```

Comment: Amigo, implementé el código pero me da un error el siguiente:

No me deja compilar si quiera.

Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\user\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\GPSur\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2323: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\user\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\GPSur\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2324: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Comment: Una opción para solucionar este error es establecer en `compileSdkVersion 28` y `targetSdkVersion 28` en dado caso de que tus versiones sean inferiores a 28, despues `Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project` o `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Comment: Gracias, decidí por la opción donde levanta la interfaz completa de settings de localización , para no tener que cambiar la versión de SDK. Gracias de igual forma.